# How to find my Artist Id for iOS Apple Developer?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need it for:
https://github.com/danielamitay/DAAppsViewController

code is:

```
DAAppsViewController *appsViewController = [[DAAppsViewController alloc] init];
[appsViewController loadAppsWithArtistId:356087517 completionBlock:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:appsViewController animated:YES];
```

This is working for me.
But this number `356087517` is for Danile, author of this library.
How do I find my own ArtistId, I know it is somehow connected to my Apple Developer account, but just do not know here to find it.
My Apple developer page is
http://appstore.com/weborcode
If somebody can find it from that, but it is hard to explain how to get it.

I looked for 15 minutes in my iTunes account, but could not find it.

I suppose this is easy, when you know where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your id is `558289887`. Open the page in iTunes, right click on the title and click copy link. The id is at the end of the copied link: https://itunes.apple.com/de/artist/web-or-code/id558289887

Answer (score 2):

I know one way, login to your `itunesconnect` account. Then follow the steps

1. Goto MyApps, click any app.
2. Look for the option below in the image click it.

   [image]
3. When you land the in iTunes Preview page, look for the option show in image below, click on it.

   [image]
4. Now look into the address bar above, you find the `artist id`, like the image below

   [image]

Use browser.

Hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: I am so sorry, but I can accept just one answer as correct.

Comment: @WebOrCode No problem, but my answer is a generic answer, not specific. It just that it should help others. Cheers.